# Google Form Enteries REST API not returing data with "date_created" Search filters

Tags: google-forms-api

I am calling Google Form Entries API from a Console application. Form Entries Get API doesn't return data with some specific dates when the date time value changes to a different date, by adding 1 second to the existing date time value API returns data.

API: https:///wp-json/gf/v2/forms//entries
Search filter : {"field_filters": [{"key":"date_created","value":"2023-04-23 22:07:47:001","operator":">="}]}

Sample HTTP call :
GET /wp-json/gf/v2/forms/12/entries?paging[page_size]=1000&search={"field_filters": [{"key":"date_created","value":"2023-04-24 03:15:40.000","operator":">="}]}&oauth_consumer_key=<consumer_key>&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=&oauth_nonce=&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature= HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Content-Type: application/json

The request should return 2 enteries